# Stopping a div from moving while scrolling

Tags: css

I have a question, I have a div that keeps moving with my scroll,and it drives me crazy because i can't fix this bug, tried a few things but they didn't work out..
Here's the link to a GIF with it:
https://i.gyazo.com/24186375915a9ede01700ac879badbc7.mp4

Comment: But... what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want it to stay where is it when you enter first on the page

Comment: Check if the element has style position:fixed .

Comment: Ok @Cristi, then we need you to edit the question an add the HTML and CSS code

Comment: Please check its position fixed. Make it position: relative;

Comment: Please share your HTML code trial.

Answer (score 0):

You Set Fixed Position on Your Div..Try to change that Css Property and then Proceed Further..